# A 'simple' way to implement Swagger in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I have a ReSTFul API written in simple Spring (no Spring Boot, no fancy stuff!). I need to implement Swagger into this. So far, EVERY page on the internet has only driven me crazy with confusing configurations and bloated code that I did not find portable at all.

Does anyone have a sample project (or a set of detailed steps) that can help me accomplish this? In particular, I am looking for a good sample that uses swagger-springmvc. I know it has 'samples', but at best, the esoteric code is discouraging.

I must clarify that I am not looking for "why Swagger is simply the best". I am not using (and for my current task will not use) Spring Boot or such.

Comment: By the samples, I assume you're referring to https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo. I'd actually encourage you to open a ticket directly on swagger-springmvc as it's important for them to know that some of their potential users may feel the docs are inadequate so that they could improve on it.

Comment: This one helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807791/swagger-for-spring-mvc-project

Comment: With latest Spec V3 - This can be useful with minimal configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Answer (score 127, accepted):

#### Springfox (Swagger spec 2.0, current)

[Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) has replaced Swagger-SpringMVC, and now supports both Swagger specs 1.2 and 2.0.  The implementation classes have changed, allowing for some deeper customization, but with some work.  The [documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) has improved, but still needs some details added for advanced configuration.  The old answer for the 1.2 implementation can still be found below.

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The bare-minimum implementation looks more-or-less the same, but now uses the `Docket` class instead of the `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("TITLE")
            .description("DESCRIPTION")
            .version("VERSION")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url")
            .license("LICENSE")
            .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com")
            .build();
    }

}
```

Your Swagger 2.0 API documentation will now be available at `http://myapp/v2/api-docs`.

> Note : If you are not using Spring boot then you should add jackson-databind dependency. Since springfox uses jackson for databinding.

Adding Swagger UI support is even easier now.  If you are using Maven, add the following dependency for the Swagger UI webjar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Spring Boot, then your web app should automatically pick up the necessary files and show the UI at `http://myapp/swagger-ui.html` (formerly: `http://myapp/springfox`).  If you are not using Spring Boot, then as yuriy-tumakha mentions in the answer below, you will need to register a resource handler for the files.  The Java configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override 
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

The new [static documentation generation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#configuring-springfox-staticdocs) feature also looks quite nice, though I have not tried it out myself.

#### Swagger-SpringMVC (Swagger spec 1.2, older)

The documentation for [Swagger-SpringMVC](https://github.com/dilipkrish/swagger-springmvc) can be a little bit confusing, but it is actually incredibly easy to set up.  The simplest configuration requires creating a `SpringSwaggerConfig` bean and enabling annotation-based configuration (which you probably already do in your Spring MVC project):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />
```

However, I think it is well worth it to take the extra step of defining a custom Swagger configuration using the `SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin`, instead of the previous XML-defined bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){

        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .includePatterns(".*api.*"); // assuming the API lives at something like http://myapp/api
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("TITLE")
            .description("DESCRIPTION")
            .version("VERSION")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url")
            .license("LICENSE")
            .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com")
            .build();
    }

}
```

When you run your application, you should now see your API spec created at `http://myapp/api-docs`.  To get the fancy Swagger UI set up, you need to clone the static files from the [GitHub project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) and put them in your project.  Make sure your project is configured to serve the static HTML files:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/" />
```

Then edit the `index.html` file at the top level of the Swagger UI `dist` directory.  Towards the top of the file, you'll see some JavaScript that refers to the `api-docs` URL of another project.  Edit this to point to your project's Swagger documentation:

```
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = url[1];
  } else {
    url = "http://myapp/api-docs";
  }
```

Now when you navigate to `http://myapp/path/to/swagger/index.html`, you should see the Swagger UI instance for your project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tutorial. I am doing something similar but still I am not able to see UI (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178370/swagger-not-showing-ui). What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What are Maven dependencies for Swagger 2 with Spring MVC?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer: I have updated the answer with the Maven dependency for Springfox.  This is the only dependency you need to include in your project, unless you also want Swagger UI or Static Docs.

Comment: Great write up on the how-to. Also, keep in mind that the [springfox](http://springfox.io) site has fairly good and upto-date documentation.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan: No bias in the comment, eh ;)  Yes, the documentation for the project is way better now, but I spent a lot of time scratching my head with the Swagger-SpringMVC docs.

Comment: @willOEM guilty as charged!

Comment: looks like the UI url is now /myapp/swagger-ui.html and not /springfox

Comment: For completeness: The 'regex' method in the springfox 'SwaggerConfig' example is from 'springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex(String)'. If took me quite a while to figure that out ;)

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add `PathSelectors.` to help people struggling with static import of `regex`

Comment: Worth noting: if following these instructions **exactly**, and not using SpringBoot, you'll get a runtime error due to the different versions of springfox and springfox-ui libraries retrieved from Maven. Instead, start out with the latest version of both if possible (`2.5.0` as I write this)

Comment: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#dependencies is a very good place to start and for further details.

Answer (score 14):

Springfox Swagger UI works for me after adding WebJar dependency and resource mappings.
http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

or Spring Annotation
https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/spring-java-swagger/src/main/java/springfoxdemo/java/swagger/SpringConfig.java

Swagger2 should be enabled

```
 @EnableSwagger2
 public class SwaggerConfiguration {
 }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, however I'm still getting a 404 on `/swagger-resources` when opening `swagger-ui.html`. Any tips? More resource mappings maybe?

Comment: It looks like swagger-resources are not in root context. It can be fixed by mapping DispatcherServlet to root context. Look at issue fix
[issue 983](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/983) and    
[Q. How does one configure swagger-ui for non-springboot applications?](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#q13)

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using swagger-maven-plugin to generate swagger.json and copy it to yours static swagger-ui.

Please check simple sample of working plugin with Spring MVC annotations on this repo:

https://github.com/khipis/swagger-maven-example

or for JAX-RS

https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-example