# How to enable Swagger UI? Tomcat, SpringMVC, REST

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, swagger, swagger-ui

My configuration is as follow:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger WebJar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

root-context.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<beans:bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />
```

I deploy my application into Tomcat 8.0. I am able to see Swagger JSON data at URI:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/api-docs
```

But I can't run Swagger UI. What more should I do to run Swagger UI in my project?

Comment: Have you tried the context root of your application? ttp://localhost:8080/myap? or ttp://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html?

Comment: I implemented a demo, but I didn't use webjar (I copied UI resources). You can check it out here: https://github.com/jxc876/boot-swagger-demo Hope it helps.

Comment: Under `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` I have got Spring Web application with `web.xml` configuration file. I put swagger-ui resources into `src\main\webapp\docs`. What should I add to web.xml to serve also that content? Under `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` I have my web app. I dont know where is swagger UI

Comment: @Mike R, The boot-swagger-demo does not work. The Hello world displays but the /api-docs does not

Comment: I use Springfox Swagger UI. You can see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33258645/3608312

Comment: I did exact same configuration, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding swagger-ui resources to

```
src\main\webapp\docs
```

I also added

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

To pom.xml

Now I can access swagger UI under:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/docs/
```

Comment: If i copy the files from swagger-ui/dist then i see only the pet example. How to get swagger-ui to use json of my webservice?

Comment: Did you enabled swagger as shown in the example? https://github.com/jxc876/boot-swagger-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mramirez/App.java

Comment: What do you mean by "adding swagger-ui resources to `src\main\webapp\docs`"? What exactly did you do?

Comment: "I also added <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> To pom.xml" I guess you mean spring xml

Answer (score 5):

The trick is that your swagger-ui maven dependency is a webjar. You need to configure the path from your webserver to the webjar.

I used the current maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And configured it with annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/2.1.3/");
    }
// [...]
}
```

Same can be done with with xml in your spring configuration:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/swagger-ui/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/2.1.3/"/>
```

Also see: http://www.jamesward.com/2012/04/30/webjars-in-spring-mvc