# Swagger: Not showing UI

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to use Swagger with Spring MVC. I have following entries in the build.gradle file

```
 compile 'com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.9.4'
 compile 'com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:1.3.12'
 compile 'org.webjars:swagger-ui:2.0.12'
```

I have enable it using @EnableSwagger annotation.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty.class, LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class App extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){

        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .includePatterns(".*feed.*"); // assuming the API lives at something like http://myapp/api
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "My Project's REST API",
                "This is a description of your API.",
                "API TOS",
                "me@wherever.com",
                "API License",
                "API License URL"
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/");
    }
}
```

But when run the application using spring boot and hit the endpoint http://localhost:8080/api-docs, I just see the response in Json,

`{"apiVersion":"1.0","apis":[{"description":"Basic Error Controller","path":"/default/basic-error-controller","position":0},{"description":"Manage people","path":"/default/people","position":0}],"authorizations":{},"info":{"contact":"Contact Email","description":"Api Description","license":"Licence Type","licenseUrl":"License URL","termsOfServiceUrl":"Api terms of service","title":"default Title"},"swaggerVersion":"1.2"}`

I copied the static files from swagger-ui and copied it to my /main/webapp/doc

I am still missing fancy UI.

Comment: Try opening either http://localhost:8080/sdoc.jsp or http://localhost:8080/app/sdoc.jsp

Comment: If you are not seeing the Swagger UI page, then your static file config is not correct.  Swagger UI is just HTML and JavaScript, so it will work regardless of whether your API is reachable or not.  Have you downloaded the proper repository files?  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

Comment: @willOEM - swagger-springmvc offers a swagger-ui package which he uses. I suspect the problem is that they are hitting the wrong URL.

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html