# Swagger integration into a NON SpringBoot project using SpringFox

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I have the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26720090/10882280). I want to integrate swagger into a **non spring boot project**. I followed the steps given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722686/10882280) which uses springfox but I am getting the following error on server startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingModelPropertiesProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:*/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar!/springfox/documentation/schema/property/CachingModelPropertiesProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'optimized': Failed to introspect bean class [springfox.documentation.schema.property.OptimizedModelPropertiesProvider] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/members/ResolvedParameterizedMember
```

These are the dependencies added:

```
             <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

UPDATE: 
So I think I was missing a jackson fasterxml dependency. I shuffled around with the pom.xml and the error went away. Still trying to zero in on the exact dependency that was creating the problem.

But though this error went away, another popped up:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/FluentIterable;
```

So then I switched to the 2.6.1 version of springfox, the second error went away and I got a good clean server start-up.

Comment: can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: I think the issue comes from another missing jar , can you post your pom.xml ?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from another missing jar, make sure you have two dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>20.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

solves the `nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable` error