# Not able to implement swagger-ui in spring-mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

I want to implement swagger-UI on my spring web-mvc project. I have tried at least 10+ tutorials from internet. But none works on my project.

In the end I am trying this solution: [see this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720090/a-simple-way-to-implement-swagger-in-a-spring-mvc-application).

Comment: How do we know what mistake you are making? Do you have a git link for the repo?

Comment: We can connect over meet. I have used the fist solution provided on the above link as it is but nothing is available on http/myapp/v2/api/docs as mentioned in solution. Can you just provide a way how to implement swagger ui in spring web MVC application

Comment: just tell me one way or any tutorials  on how to implement swagger in spring web mvc project. This is a production application, so can't share code repository. We have used spring web mvc 4.0.0 and spring-security also.

Comment: have you tried this example ?  https://josdem.io/techtalk/spring/spring_swagger_java_configuration/

Comment: Not tried this, going to try now. meanwhile a doubt, will swagger generate doc for class anotated with RestController  only or  class anotated with Controller also.